# Como organizar las cards bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

necesito una ayudita con cards en bootstrap 4 , usé el siguiente codigo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>tittle</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <section class="container borde" id="cards">
    <article class="row">
      <div class="card-group text-center p-5">
        <div class="card m-3">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title mt-3 mb-3">Card title</h4>
            <p class="card-text mt-3 mb-3 p-2">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary ">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card m-3">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title mt-3 mb-3">Card title</h4>
            <p class="card-text mt-3 mb-3 p-2">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

          </div>
          <div class="card-footer">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary ">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card m-3">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body mt-3 mb-3">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
            <p class="card-text mt-3 mb-3 p-2">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This card has even longer content than the first to show that equal height action.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary ">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card m-3">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title mt-3 mb-3">Card title</h4>
            <p class="card-text mt-3 mb-3 p-2">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This card has even longer content than the first to show that equal height action.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary ">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>
  </section>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Si lo ejecutan y lo ven ampliado, las cards se ve bien en xs, lg, y xl. En sm y md se ven las cards como aplastadas, intenté que en sm se viera apilado como en xs, y md que se vieran 2 cards por fila poniendo col a cada card pero no me funcionó. Lo que quiero hacer es que en xs sm se vean apilados uno debajo del otro, en sm que sea cards de 2, y en lg xl que sea de 4(que esto está por defecto)
[image: xs se ve bien]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Saludos. Prueba quitando `<div class="card-group text-center p-5">` (y su </div> que le corresponde) y entonces a cada `card` agregarle los `col-xl-N`y demás conforme a la distribución que deseas para cada tamaño; al final agregar `col-1` este se aplicara a todos los demás tamaños no especificados.

Comment: Si vas a trabajar con la grilla de Bootstrap, te sugiero usar los elementos `col` como contenedores para tus elementos de tipo `card`. Toma en cuenta que la especificación de Bootstrap establece que los elementos `col` deben ser hijos directos de un elemento tipo `row` para que la grilla funcione tal como se espera. Saludos

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda pude solucionarlo con lo que me dijeron me guie perfecto!